# Why is my If statement not working when I compare three numbers?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

*I have this Code but it is not working :*

```
double N1 = int.Parse(TB_S1.Text);
double N2 = int.Parse(TB_S2.Text);
double N3 = int.Parse(TB_S3.Text);
double N4 = int.Parse(TB_P1Y.Text);
double N5 = int.Parse(TB_P2X.Text);

double N11 = N1 + N2;
double N6 = N2 + N3;
double N7 = N3 + N4;

double R;

if ((N11 = N6 = N7))
{
    messageBox.Show("Corect");
}
```

Edit: 
solution: th eproblem was using single = instead of ==

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: You need to add some more detail. It's impossible to tell, based on what you've posted, exactly what might be wrong. Are you getting an Exception?

Comment: Always post the full error message(s). I suspect this will fail to compile.

Comment: henceforth known as "the Skeetlist"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To handle your comparison, you need:

```
if ((N11 == N6) && (N11 == N7))
```

Or, simplified:

```
if (N11 == N6 && N11 == N7)
```

Note the `==` (comparison) instead of `=` (assignment).  Also, you need to do two separate comparisons to check to see if the three values are equal.

In addition, right now you're using `int.Parse`, but assigning to a `double`.  You should likely use `double.Parse` instead:

```
double N1 = double.Parse(TB_S1.Text);
```

You may also want to consider using `double.TryParse`, as this will better handle errors in user input:

```
double N1;
if(!double.TryParse(TB_S1.Text, out N1))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid value in TB_S1");
    return;
}
```

Comment: +1 - better answer than mine, but where's your hat?!?! :)

Comment: @AdamRackis I have a few - not sure why they're not showing up, though

Answer (score 6):

The problem is most likely this line

```
if ((N11 = N6 = N7))
```

`=` in C# is assignment; you're most likely looking for equality, which is `==`

Changing the above to this should fix it for you.

```
if (N11 == N6 && N11 == N7)
```

Comment: @Reed - I ninja edited that problem away :)

Comment: @MarcB - there was a bug in my original answer -- it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
 if ((N11 == N6) && (N11 == N7))
```

instead of

```
 if ((N11 = N6 = N7))
```